# How to get the value of a selected option dynamically and store it into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var temparr = [];
var arrmain = [
  ["E1", "RAM", "CHENNAI", "COMP", "P1"],
  ["E2", "RAJU", "PUNE", "ELECTRO", "P1"],
  ["E3", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"]
  ["E4", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"]
];
var p_id;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dropdown select').on('change', function() {
    p_id = $('#dropdown select :selected').val();
  });




  for (var i = 0; i < temparr.length; i++) {
    //creates option tag
    $('<option/>', {
      value: tempArray[i],
      html: tempArray[i]
    }).appendTo('#dropdown select');

  }
});
```

```html
<div id='dropdown'>
  <select style="width:200px">

  </select>
</div>
```

I having dropdown which is getting option from array now when i change option then want to get that selected option value into variable.so how can i get that vlaue into variable whenever i change option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of `temparr` you need to iterate over `arrmain` array.

You are also missing a comma in your array of arrays.

Try this

```js
var temparr = [];
var arrmain = [
  ["E1", "RAM", "CHENNAI", "COMP", "P1"],
  ["E2", "RAJU", "PUNE", "ELECTRO", "P1"],
  ["E3", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"],
  ["E4", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"]
];
var p_id;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dropdown select').on('change', function() {
    p_id = $('#dropdown select :selected').val();
    alert(p_id)
  });


  for (var i = 0; i < arrmain.length; i++) {

    
    $('<option/>', {
      value: arrmain[i],
      html: arrmain[i]
    }).appendTo('#dropdown select');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dropdown'>
  <select style="width:200px">

  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript code like this

```
var temparr = [];
var arrmain = [
["E1", "RAM", "CHENNAI", "COMP", "P1"],
["E2", "RAJU", "PUNE", "ELECTRO", "P1"],
["E3", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"]
["E4", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"]
];
var p_id;
$(document).ready(function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < arrmain.length; i++) {
        //creates option tag
        $('<option/>', {
            value: arrmain[i],
            html: arrmain[i]
        }).appendTo('#dropdown select');

    }

    $('#dropdown select').on('change', function () {

        p_id = $('#dropdown select').val();
        alert(p_id);
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit differently, you can use `change` to fill drop down. and simply get on on `change`. See below code.

```js
var temparr = [];
var arrmain = [
  ["E1", "RAM", "CHENNAI", "COMP", "P1"],
  ["E2", "RAJU", "PUNE", "ELECTRO", "P1"],
  ["E3", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"],
  ["E4", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"]
];
var p_id;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dropdown select').on('change', function() {
    p_id = $('#dropdown select').val();
    alert(p_id)
  });

$.each(arrmain,function(e,i){
       $('<option/>', {
      value: i,
      html: i
    }).appendTo('#dropdown select');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dropdown'>
  <select style="width:200px">

  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code

```
<select id="dropdown">
        <option value="">---select---</option>

</select>
```

Do add jQuery.js file in your html file.

jQuery code-

```
$(function () {

    var select = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var options = [["E1", "RAM", "CHENNAI", "COMP", "P1"],
                   ["E2", "RAJU", "PUNE", "ELECTRO", "P1"],
                   ["E3", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"],
                   ["E4", "JOHN", "KOLKATA", "MECH", "P2"]];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }

    $("#dropdown").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);             
    });
});
```